# How to resolve ".then is not a function" with node-7zip

Tags: node.js, electron

I am using node.js (an Electron app) to process a number of ZIP archives and I am using node-7zip and 7zip-bin libraries. To do the processing of one file after another, required for the logic of the app, I have written the following recursive function:

```
function processArchive(pdscQueue, archiveFilename, repoPath) {
    let tempFolder = tmp.dirSync() ;
    let devicePackFile = path.join(repoPath,archiveFilename) ;   // Create a temp folder for the extacted data
    sevenZip.extractFull(devicePackFile, tempFolder.name, { $bin: pathTo7zip})

    .then( function () {
        //
        // Process the file here ...
        //
        tempFolder.removeCallback() ;   // Clean up
        //
        // Check if there are more to process
        //
        if ( pdscQueue.isEmpty()) {
            return ;
        } else {
            processArchive(pdscQueue, pdscQueue.dequeue(), repoPath ) ;
        }
    });
}
```

The issue I have is that I get ".then is not a function" when I try to run the code.

Google and StackOverFlow searches have not revealed a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't know why the original post I made above gives the error, I have found a solution that works for me by using an event from the node-7zip library:

```
function processArchive(pdscQueue, archiveFilename, repoPath) {
    let tempFolder = tmp.dirSync() ;
    let devicePackFile = path.join(repoPath,archiveFilename) ;   // Create a temp folder for the extacted data
    let theStream = sevenZip.extractFull(devicePackFile, tempFolder.name, { $bin: pathTo7zip}) ;

    theStream.on('end', () => {
        //
        // Process the file here ...
        //
        tempFolder.removeCallback() ;   // Clean up
        //
        // Check if there are more to process
        //
        if ( pdscQueue.isEmpty()) {
            return ;
        } else {
            processArchive(pdscQueue, pdscQueue.dequeue(), repoPath ) ;
        }
    }) ;
}
```

Maybe this approach will also be useful for someone else.